# How to install Ghostscript in aws Lambda?

Tags: ghostscript, python-camelot

Error Message: `Please make sure that Ghostscript is installed", "errorType": "RuntimeError"`

```py
import camelot

def pdfToJson(event=None, context=None): 
    tables = camelot.read_pdf("./week-1-2019-20.pdf")  
    tables[0].df.to_json("./sample.json")
```

1. Installed the dependencies with pip install  -t .
2. But still getting the error.

How can I install the "ghostscript" dependency in my python code?

Comment: The quality of your post would be better if you removed "_(“errorMessage”: “Please make sure that Ghostscript is installed”, “errorType”: “RuntimeError”)_" from the title and placed it in your post ; )

Comment: I do not have edit privilege

Comment: Thanks for reply _ I have edited the post as per my suggestion

Comment: okay. you are welcome

Comment: Have you installed Ghostscript (or verified that Ghostscript is installled) ? You may need the Python bindings for Ghostscript as well, which are available here: https://pypi.org/project/ghostscript/

Comment: I have installed the dependencies of ghostscript. And folder of ghostscript is already there in the code folder

Comment: Ghostscript is a software dependency, make sure the installation is in the virtual environment of the Lambda Package.

Comment: Same has been tried. But still same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this myself, but you should be able to do this with a Lambda Layer. You can see an example of how this is done via https://github.com/BearTail/ghostscript-aws-lambda-layer.

Some magic may also be needed to tell camelot that the Ghostscript binary can be found at /opt/bin/gs, as that isn't a normal location for it.

Answer (score -2):

In `camelot` library communication with `Ghostscript` done via a low-level C-API interface with `ctypes` usage. Ghostscript is used to generate images from pdf being processed by the library.

You do not need to install any python binding by yourself, the only requirement is Ghostscript itself.  The easiest way to install is to use [repositories/CD](https://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/tasks/Ghostscript-install.html#flash-install__ul_k5l_czh_lj), on Ubuntu simple as that:

```
sudo apt-get install -y ghostscript
gs --version
```

Comment: How do I install in aws Lambda?

Comment: @GoutamGhosh it depends on the package manager that used. The link above contains information on how to install for other systems.

Comment: I'm marking this down as AWS Lambda doesn't provide the ability to customize packages available within the runtime.